# Quel est le mot français le plus long ?

Tags: demande-de-mot, lexique

Sans tenir compte des mots empruntés (surtout de l'allemand), quel est le mot le plus long du français ?

Comment: easily answered by a basic search

Comment: Wikipédia [répond très bien à cette question](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mots_les_plus_longs_en_fran%C3%A7ais), y a-t-il quelque chose de plus à ajouter ? Si oui, il faut préciser la question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Anticonstitutionnellement* est généralement considéré comme le mot français le plus long. Il est célèbre pour ça chez les francophones. C'est effectivement le mot le plus long dans la plupart des dictionnaires.

Il n'y a pas en français d'emprunts aussi long. On n'importe que des mots suffisamment courts pour être retenus ! Le mot *anticonstitutionnellement* est construit à partir d'une racine (*constitu-*), du préfixe *anti-*, et de plusieurs suffixes :

- *-tion* pour former un nom
- *-(n)el* pour former un adjectif se rapportant à un nom
- *-(le)ment* pour former un adverbe se rapportant à un adjectif

On peut former des mots arbitrairement longs avec les règles de nommage des composés chimiques. Mais il ne s'agit plus de mots du vocabulaire ordinaire.

Comment: Ah, le souvenir des cours de récréation... Qui n'a pas, malgré le sens totalement obscur du mot à cet age, rencontré *anticonstitutionnellement* dans l'une d'elles ? ;-)

Comment: @Gilles Que se cache t-il derrière le "*généralement considéré*"? Y a t-il d'autres mots plus longs mais non-approuvés ? Merci :)

Comment: @Mistalis C'est le mot « courant » le plus long, mais on peut toujours trouver des termes techniques qui forment des agrégats plus longs, par exemple des composés chimiques.

Answer (score 0):

Je voterais bien pour **"anticonstitutionnellement"** mais je n'en suis pas complètement certain.